# Choose different screens on content item action light switch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am very much new to light switch and need to build a small application, in which there will be some categories on first screen.  Based on the user selection, I need to open different screens.

For example, on first screen categories will be like:

1. Tiger
2. Lion
3. Deer

If the user chooses Tiger, I need to open one screen; if Lion is chosen, then I need to open another screen.  Each category opens a different screen.

How do I do that with light switch?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x=screen.details.properties.Screenname.value.selectedItem.screenfield;

if(x=='desired value')
{
    this.myapp.showXXXscreen();
}
```

```html
var x=screen.details.properties.Screenname.value.selectedItem.screenfield;

if(x=='desired value')
{
    this.myapp.showXXXscreen();
}
```